# Installing Windows 7 onto a Raid 5 setup without an install disk. Can it be done?

Tags: windows-7, windows, raid, swap

I am upgrading my motherboard from a crappy dell prefab to a [Foxconn Inferno Katana](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813186176). I am also upgrading my ram from crappy stock dell ram to G.Skill.

I have decided to set up a raid system, now that my motherboard supports it. This means I must swap my OS over to my new drives. I don't have an install disk however. When I initially purchased this computer, it came with Windows Vista. Using my sweet student upgrade, I moved up to Windows 7 Home Premium. This of course means I do not have a disk for 7.

Is there any way to install Windows 7 without the original install disk onto a raid 5 format?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. I would recommend you at least have it handy though, as there are numerous factors that could cause your install to not boot at all.  With your student upgrade, you were eligible to download the upgrade disk in an ISO.  At the very least, I'd copy all the files onto a USB.  There are numerous guides on how to make a Windows Install USB. I'd keep that handy.

Without knowing your current hardware though, the safest bet is to use Sysprep. But that destroys some of your customizations.  If your current hardware matches up pretty good to your new hardware, then the biggest change would just be to install some RAID drivers.  I'm assuming you are using the builtin Intel controller to do a RAID 5.

Image your current disk with your favorite imaging program.  Clonezilla is a popular favorite. When you setup your new board, you'll need to format the drives using the Intel Storage Manager.

Copy the image back and cross your fingers.

I know this answer sounds real general, but you didn't list your current hardware, so I wrote the guide for "general" hardware.